# Query result found but not displayed in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Well, I don't really see this one.
This is a simple page where I try to display results of a joined query.

Here is the controller code :

```
public function pageApproachUpdateAction($pageId)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $pageWithMapItems = $em->getRepository('bndmyBundle:Page')->getPageWithMapItems($pageId);
    return $this->render('bndmyBundle:test.html.twig', array(
        'pageWithMapItems'     => $pageWithMapItems
    ));
```

Here is the query :

```
public function getPageWithMapItems($pageId) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->leftJoin('p.mapItems', 'm')
           ->where('p.id = :pageId')
                ->setParameter('pageId', $pageId)
           ->addSelect('m');

    return $qb->getQuery()
           ->getSingleResult();
}
```

Here is the twig code :

```
<body>
    {% for mapitem in pageWithMapItems %}
        item {{mapitem.id}}<br/>
    {% else %}
    No result
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Here is the Page entity :

```
<?php

namespace bnd\myBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="bnd\myBundle\Entity\PageRepository")
*/
class Page
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="bnd\myBundle\Entity\Route", mappedBy="page")
 */
private $routes;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="bnd\myBundle\Entity\MapItem", mappedBy="page")
 */
private $mapItems;

/**
 * @var smallint $number
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="smallint")
 */
private $number;

/**
 * @var string $background
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="background", type="string", length=255, nullable="true")
 */
private $background;

/**
 * @var string $type
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string $description
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable="true")
 */
private $description;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}



/**
 * Set background
 *
 * @param string $background
 */
public function setBackground($background)
{
    $this->background = $background;
}

/**
 * Get background
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getBackground()
{
    return $this->background;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}


public function __construct()
{
    $this->routes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->mapItems = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add routes
 *
 * @param bnd\myBundle\Entity\Route $routes
 */
public function addRoute(\bnd\myBundle\Entity\Route $routes)
{
    $this->routes[] = $routes;
}

/**
 * Get routes
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRoutes()
{
    return $this->routes;
}

/**
 * Set number
 *
 * @param smallint $number
 */
public function setNumber($number)
{
    $this->number = $number;
}

/**
 * Get number
 *
 * @return smallint 
 */
public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->number;
}

/**
 * Add mapItems
 *
 * @param bnd\myBundle\Entity\MapItem $mapItems
 */
public function addMapItem(\bnd\myBundle\Entity\MapItem $mapItems)
{
    $this->mapItems[] = $mapItems;
}

/**
 * Get mapItems
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getMapItems()
{
    return $this->mapItems;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param text $description
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
}
```

And the MapItem entity :

```
namespace bnd\myBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * bnd\myBundle\Entity\MapItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="bnd\myBundle\Entity\MapItemRepository")
 */
class MapItem
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="mapItems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $page;

/**
 * @var string $type
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string $latlng
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="latlng", type="text")
 */
private $latlng;

/**
 * @var string $description
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Set latlng
 *
 * @param string $latlng
 */
public function setLatlng($latlng)
{
    $this->latlng = $latlng;
}

/**
 * Get latlng
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLatlng()
{
    return $this->latlng;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set page
 *
 * @param bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page $page
 */
public function setPage(\bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page $page)
{
    $this->page = $page;
}

/**
 * Get page
 *
 * @return bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page 
 */
public function getPage()
{
    return $this->page;
}
}
```

No result is displayed, but there should be one!

I don't have any exception, no typo mistakes I guess

I checked the profiler to read the actual queries performed ; I tested them with PhpMyAdmin, and none of them have no result.

It's a very simple and basic case. So, what did I did wrong ?
Thanks :)

Comment: did you try a var_dump of your $pageWithMapItems ? You got result ? Can you show us your getPageWithMapItems method?

Comment: I just added the query to the intial post. I made a  {{ dump(pageWithMapItems) }} : the object(bnd\myBundle\Entity\Page) has a private 'mapItems'. But I can't see any of the expected values of the mapItem I try to display.

Comment: I was talking about a var_dump in php just after your request, do you have result in it?

Comment: Well, I have a clue; mapItem is always written with a I in the entities, but the table name in PhpMyAdmin is mapitem, with a i. Could this be a problem ?

Comment: I changed the controller to return only the var_dump : return new Response(var_dump($pageWithMapItems)); I have the page result, but not the linked mapItems..

Comment: don't return the var_dump, do it between your request and your return : add this ligne just after `$pageWithMapItems = $em->getRepository('bndmyBundle:Page')->getPageWithMapItems($pageId);` => `var_dump($pageWithMapItems);die();` like this you'll have the content of your php request

Comment: Thanks. I did that. There isn't any data for the linked mapItem

Comment: Your page object is empty? Or just your relation to mapItem is empty?

Comment: The page object has data for the page level, and the relation to mapItem is described (snapshot, association, em..) according to the entity class, but there's no data for the mapItem level.

Comment: okay, so can you show us your entities? (page + mapitem) it should be a relation issue

Comment: Yes, I came to think of that too. I re-read the entities several times. And queries shown by the profiler seem to be fine...

Comment: Did you generate your entities from database? And you didn't fill the joincolumn in your mapitem entity (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)

Comment: I used the console to generate the entities.
I filled the joinColumn like this: @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)

Comment: yes but you generate your entities from the database or you created them in php and add them to the database after? (still nothing with the joincolumn?)

Comment: I create them from the console or the php entity files. And I update the database after with doctrine:schema:update --force  No change with the joincolumn ; but I think it's optionnal...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17876/discussion-between-coussinsky-and-yako)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the thing is you've a one-to-many on your mapItems, so doctrine will return you an arrayCollection.

Your mapItems wasn't displayed in twig because you have to make your for loop on pageWithMapItems.mapItems, if you do it directly on pageWithMapItems it'll not work because your pageWithMapItems variable contain un object of page and not an array.

So this should work:

```
<body>
    {% for mapitem in pageWithMapItems.mapItems %}
        item {{mapitem.id}}<br/>
    {% else %}
         No result
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Hope i'm clear !